# How can I wrap a group of adjacent elements using XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have some XML with `<ListItem>` elements, and I'd like to wrap any consecutive runs with `<List>` elements. So, source XML would look something like this:

```
<Section>
  <Head>Heading</Head>
  <Para>Blah</Para>
  <ListItem>item 1</ListItem>
  <ListItem>item 2</ListItem>
  <ListItem>item 3</ListItem>
  <ListItem>item 4</ListItem>
  <Para>Something else</Para>
</Section>
```

And I'd want to convert it to something like this:

```
<Section>
  <Head>Heading</Head>
  <Para>Blah</Para>
  <List>
    <ListItem>item 1</ListItem>
    <ListItem>item 2</ListItem>
    <ListItem>item 3</ListItem>
    <ListItem>item 4</ListItem>
  </List>
  <Para>Something else</Para>
</Section>
```

using XSLT. I'm sure it's obvious but I can't work it out at this time in the evening. Thanks!

---

**Edit:** this can be safely ignored by most people.

This XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Root>
  <Story>
    <Section id="preface">
      <ChapterTitle>Redacted</ChapterTitle>
      <HeadA>Redacted</HeadA>
      <Body>Redacted</Body>
      <BulletListItem>Item1</BulletListItem>
      <BulletListItem>Item2</BulletListItem>
      <BulletListItem>Item3</BulletListItem>
      <BulletListItem>Item4</BulletListItem>
      <HeadA>Redacted</HeadA>
      <Body>Redacted</Body>
      <HeadA>Redacted</HeadA>
      <Body>Redacted</Body>
      <Body>Redacted<Italic>REDACTED</Italic>Redacted</Body>
      <BulletListItem>Second list Item1</BulletListItem>
      <BulletListItem>Second list Item2</BulletListItem>
      <BulletListItem>Second list Item3</BulletListItem>
      <BulletListItem>Second list Item4</BulletListItem>
      <Body>Redacted</Body>
    </Section>
  </Story>
</Root>
```

With this XSL:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:key name="kFollowing" match="BulletListItem[preceding-sibling::*[1][self::BulletListItem]]"
  use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::BulletListItem
         [not(preceding-sibling::*[1][self::BulletListItem])])"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="BulletListItem
         [not(preceding-sibling::*[1][self::BulletListItem])]">
  <BulletList>
    <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates mode="copy" select="key('kFollowing', generate-id())"/>
  </BulletList>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="BulletListItem[preceding-sibling::*[1][self::BulletListItem]]"/>

 <xsl:template match="BulletListItem" mode="copy">
  <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When processed with Ruby REXML and XML/XSLT produces this XML (output prettyprint):

```
<Root>
  <Story>
    <Section id='preface'>
      <ChapterTitle>
        Redacted
      </ChapterTitle>
      <HeadA>
        Redacted
      </HeadA>
      <Body>
        Redacted
      </Body>
      <BulletList>
        <BulletListItem>
          Item1
        </BulletListItem>
        <BulletListItem>
          Item2
        </BulletListItem>
        <BulletListItem>
          Item3
        </BulletListItem>
        <BulletListItem>
          Item4
        </BulletListItem>
        <BulletListItem>
          Second list Item2
        </BulletListItem>
        <BulletListItem>
          Second list Item3
        </BulletListItem>
        <BulletListItem>
          Second list Item4
        </BulletListItem>
      </BulletList>
      <HeadA>
        Redacted
      </HeadA>
      <Body>
        Redacted
      </Body>
      <HeadA>
        Redacted
      </HeadA>
      <Body>
        Redacted
      </Body>
      <Body>
        Redacted
        <Italic>
          REDACTED
        </Italic>
        Redacted
      </Body>
      <BulletList>
        <BulletListItem>
          Second list Item1
        </BulletListItem>
      </BulletList>
      <Body>
        Redacted
      </Body>
    </Section>
  </Story>
</Root>
```

You'll see that the two lists get jammed together and the bit in between gets lost. Not sure if this is a bug in the Ruby libraries or in your XSLT.

Comment: I'm too laizy for searching duplicates... If someone post the links I'll delete the answer.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for an efficient, key based solution.

Comment: I take back what I say about it being obvious :P I really need to learn XSLT properly ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()[1]"/>
        </xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::node()[1]"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="ListItem">
        <List>
            <xsl:call-template name="ListItem"/>
        </List>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::node()
                                      [not(self::ListItem)][1]"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="ListItem[preceding-sibling::node()[1]
                                              /self::ListItem]"
                  name="ListItem">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()[1]"/>
        </xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::node()[1]
                                                 /self::ListItem"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<Section>
    <Head>Heading</Head>
    <Para>Blah</Para>
    <List>
        <ListItem>item 1</ListItem>
        <ListItem>item 2</ListItem>
        <ListItem>item 3</ListItem>
        <ListItem>item 4</ListItem>
    </List>
    <Para>Something else</Para>
</Section>
```

**Edit 3**: Using `strip-space` for what it is.

Comment: @Alejandro - strange... When I run this stylesheet on the given input, I get something very different. In particular, your `select="following-sibling::node()[1][self::ListItem]"` misses the following ListItem because the first following sibling node is a whitespace text node. Yet I see no reason (http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#strip) why that node was not stripped. I'm confused?!

Comment: @Alejandro: PS this happened in Saxon 6.5.5 in Oxygen. There are no xml:space="preserve" attributes anywhere.

Comment: @Alejandro: Good answer as always, +1.

Comment: @Skilldrick: No problem. I'm just glad this could help you.

Comment: @LasrH: That's the way Saxon deals with white space only text nodes. I'll edit this for you.

Comment: @Alejandro - I've accepted yours now because there's some kind of strange bug with the other one, and yours works great.

Comment: @Skilldrick: That may be a problem with the key. I've built this to wrap only adjacent elements imagining that you would probably have more than one list.

Comment: @Alejandro Thanks. Dimitre's now updated his version, and it works now.

Comment: @Skilldrick: I'm sure. You should understand both technics: the fine grained traversal identity and the full recursive identity with modes.

Answer (score 6):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:key name="kFollowing" match="ListItem[preceding-sibling::*[1][self::ListItem]]"
  use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::ListItem
         [not(preceding-sibling::*[1][self::ListItem])][1])"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="ListItem
         [not(preceding-sibling::*[1][self::ListItem])]">
  <List>
    <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates mode="copy" select="key('kFollowing', generate-id())"/>
  </List>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="ListItem[preceding-sibling::*[1][self::ListItem]]"/>

 <xsl:template match="ListItem" mode="copy">
  <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<Section>
  <Head>Heading</Head>
  <Para>Blah</Para>
  <ListItem>item 1</ListItem>
  <ListItem>item 2</ListItem>
  <ListItem>item 3</ListItem>
  <ListItem>item 4</ListItem>
  <Para>Something else</Para>
</Section>
```

**produces the wanted result**:

```
<Section>
    <Head>Heading</Head>
    <Para>Blah</Para>
    <List>
        <ListItem>item 1</ListItem>
        <ListItem>item 2</ListItem>
        <ListItem>item 3</ListItem>
        <ListItem>item 4</ListItem>
    </List>
    <Para>Something else</Para>
</Section>
```

Comment: @Dimitre: +1 Good answer. I was going to add this type of solution when I saw your.

Comment: @Dimitre - I've discovered a bug with this. I've reproduced the case in my question.

Comment: @Skilldrick: I don't see any change to your question and my transformation produces exactly the required result. ???

Comment: @Dimitre - Sorry, I've been updating my question. Try it out and see if you have the same problem.

Comment: @Skilldrick: Yes, there was a minor problem. I edited my solution and added 4 characters to the `<xsl:key>`. It works with your new example -- please, try it.

Comment: @Dimitre - that did it, thanks! I'm going to leave Alejandro's accepted, as he needs the rep more :) It's a bit of an arbitrary decision anyway.