# Using XSLT 1.0 to wrap sibling elements of a header

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I'm working with XSLT 1.0 from PHP and want to wrap all the sibling elements after a heading (h2) into a div so I can toggle them.

The input would look like

```
...
<h2>Nth title</h2>
<first child>...</first child>
...
<last child>...</last child>
<h2>N+1st title</h2>
...
```

and the output should be

```
...
<h2>Nth title</h2>
<div>
  <first child>...</first child>
  ...
  <last child>...</last child>
</div>
<h2>N+1st title</h2>
...
```

Is there a way to do this in XSLT 1.0?

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete, short and easy solution that is based on the most fundamental and powerful XSLT design pattern and that is efficiently using keys.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I wrap a group of adjacent elements using XSLT?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3962161/how-can-i-wrap-a-group-of-adjacent-elements-using-xslt)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This transformation:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:key name="kFollowing" match="node()[not(self::h2)]"
  use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::h2[1])"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="h2">
  <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
  <div>
   <xsl:apply-templates mode="copy"
       select="key('kFollowing', generate-id())"/>
  </div>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="node()[not(self::h2)][preceding-sibling::h2]"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()" mode="copy">
  <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on this XML document:**

```
<html>
    <h2>Nth title</h2>
    <first-child>...</first-child> ... 
    <last-child>...</last-child>
    <h2>N+1st title</h2> ...
    <x/>
     <y/>
     <z/>
</html>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
<html>
   <h2>Nth title</h2>
   <div>
      <first-child>...</first-child> ... 

      <last-child>...</last-child>
   </div>
   <h2>N+1st title</h2>
   <div> ...

      <x></x>
      <y></y>
      <z></z>
   </div>
</html>
```

**Explanation**:

1. The identity rule/template copies every node "as-is".
2. The identity rule is overriden for `h2` elements. Here the action is to copy the `h2` element and then to output a `div` and inside it to apply templates (in a special mode) to all nodes (that are not `h2` themselves) for which this `h2` element is the first preceding-sibling `h2` element.
3. The nodes to include in the previous step are conveniently defined as an `<xsl:key>` instruction.
4. In order to stop the nodes that are wrapped in `div` to be output again by the identity rule, we provide a template matching such nodes, that simply ignores them.

Comment: Worked perfectly thanks.  I will need some time to understand it though!

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Make a template that matches h2 elements; within that template, you can select all following siblings before the next h2 using this xpath expression: `following-sibling::*[count(preceding-sibling::h2[1] | current()) = 1]`.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't see how this would work.  Perhaps I should explain that I want to copy the input document except I want to wrap h2 siblings into a div.  I'm too inexperienced with XSLT to see how your expression would work as my copy selectors will anyway select the h2 siblings?