# JIBX binding and Google Contacts with flexible=true

Tags: java, xml, binding, google-contacts-api, jibx

I have a simple binding:

```
<binding>
    <mapping name="entry" class="google.vo.GoogleContactsEntry" ordered="false">
        <value name="title" field="title" usage="optional" />
        <value name="email" field="email" usage="optional" />   
    </mapping>


    <mapping name="feed" class="google.vo.GoogleContacts" ordered="false" flexible="true">
        <namespace uri="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" default="elements"/>
        <value name="id" field="id" usage="optional" />
        <value name="updated" field="updatedString" usage="optional" />
        <value name="title" field="title" usage="optional" />
        <collection item-type="google.vo.GoogleContactsEntry" name="entries" field="entries"/>
    </mapping>
</binding>
```

The problem is in Collection element, which **needs** *name="entries"*. Google returns entries **without** a wrapping element. Just like this:

```
<feed>

    <entry>

    </entry>

    <entry>

    </entry>

</feed>
```

And JiBX expects:

```
<feed>
    <entries>
        <entry>

        </entry>

        <entry>

        </entry>
    <entries>       
</feed>
```

Without element name in the binding scheme at collection, JiBX doesn't compile. Is there a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notorious work-A-round:

```
resp = StringUtils.replaceOnce(resp, "<entry>", "<entries><entry>");
resp = StringUtils.replaceOnce(resp, "</feed>", "</entries></feed>");
```

Answer (score 3):

Better solution will be use of xsl transformation and change your incoming response into expected by jibx, it should be simple.

This topic will help: 
[How can I wrap a group of adjacent elements using XSLT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3962161/how-can-i-wrap-a-group-of-adjacent-elements-using-xslt)