# Wrapping XML elements into groups in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I'm trying to write some XSLT that modifies output from a service and group it into a logical structure for consumption. However, I'm at a loss on how to do this.

Below is the output of the service. The only thing for sure is that the items are returned like this although there are sub-nodes inside each of the ellipses.

**Output**

```
<items>
  <text>...</text>
  <text>...</text>
  <text>...</text>
  <text>...</text>
  <comment>...</comment>
  <comment>...</comment>
  <comment>...</comment>
  <comment>...</comment>
  <discussion>...</discussion>
  <discussion>...</discussion>
  <discussion>...</discussion>
  <discussion>...</discussion>
  <information>...</information>
  <information>...</information>
  <information>...</information>
  <information>...</information>
</items>
```

**Desired**

```
<items>
  <item>
    <text>...</text>
    <comment>...</comment>
    <discussion>...</discussion>
    <information>...</information>
  </item>
  <item>
    <text>...</text>
    <comment>...</comment>
    <discussion>...</discussion>
    <information>...</information>
  </item>
  <item>
    <text>...</text>
    <comment>...</comment>
    <discussion>...</discussion>
    <information>...</information>
  </item>
  <item>
    <text>...</text>
    <comment>...</comment>
    <discussion>...</discussion>
    <information>...</information>
  </item>
</items>
```

I'm pretty sure this is possible in XSLT (1.0) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3962161) is probably as close as I can find to what I'm looking to do, although that question is based on only one element, whereas I have multiple nodes.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In future its good practise to include code to demonstrate what you've tried and what isn't working, rather than jus tasking for people to write your code.

Comment: @Lego Stormtroopr Thank you for the feedback. Firstly, I've been on SO for a while, so I know how it works. Secondly, it's pretty clear that what I was trying to do wasn't working. I already pointed the user to the question that I had been using as a template to find my answer, so this should give them enough information to determine whether I'm going in the right direction or not. In this case, I was not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
<xsl:template match="items">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="text"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text">
  <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()"/>
  <item>
    <xsl:copy-of select=". | ../comment[$pos] | ../discussion[$pos] | ../information[$pos]"/>
  </item>
</xsl:template>
```

to create the structure, only needs

```
<xsl:output indent="yes"/>
```

to look nice.

Comment: Yep, that's the one! Many thanks. I'm not sure exactly what tree I was barking up!