# XML formatting using XSLT

Tags: java, xml, xslt

How do I group similar tags at the same level under one tag ?
I have pasted the sample outcome with my sample xsl using xslt 1.0
Only the subsection which are adjacent to each other need to be grouped together. If there are other subsections at the same level which are not adjacent to the previous set of subsection, those need to be grouped separately...

Thanks in Advance
This is my input xml

```
<body>
  This is a generic section which is considered the first paragraph<para><paratext>this is a sub para</paratext></para> 
  <subsection>
    <para>
      <paratext>LIST ITEM 1</paratext>
    </para>
  </subsection>
  <subsection>
    <para>
      <paratext>LIST ITEM 2</paratext>
    </para>
    <subsection>
      <para>
        <paratext>CHILD LISt ITEM2 ITEM 1 </paratext>
      </para>
    </subsection>
    <subsection>
      <para>
        <paratext>CHILD LISt ITEM2 ITEM 2 </paratext>
      </para>
    </subsection>
  </subsection>
</body>
```

This is my expected result

```
        <text>
          This is a generic section which is considered the first paragraph<p>this is a sub para </p> 
           <ul>
              <li>LIST ITEM 1</li>
              <li>LIST ITEM 2</li>
              <ul> 
                  <li>CHILD LIST ITEM2 ITEM1</li>
                  <li>CHILD LIST ITEM2 ITEM2</li>
              </ul>
            </ul>
        </text>
```

With the following xsl

```
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:template match="/body">
    <text>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </text>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="/body/subsection">
    <ul>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </ul>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="/body/subsection/subsection">
    <ul>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </ul>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="/body/subsection/subsection/para/paratext">
    <li>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </li>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="/body/subsection/para/paratext">
    <li>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </li>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="body/para/paratext">
    <p>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </p>
</xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

I was able to get the following result

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <text>
   This is a generic section which is considered the first paragraph<p>this is a sub para</p>
<ul>
    <li>LIST ITEM 1</li>
</ul>`enter code here`
<ul>
    <li>LIST ITEM 2</li>
    <ul>
        <li>CHILD LISt ITEM2 ITEM 1 </li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li>CHILD LISt ITEM2 ITEM 2 </li>
    </ul>
</ul>
    </text>
```

Comment: In your source `........` doesn't appear in your result, and it's not trivial do know where `CHILD LISt ITEM2 ITEM 1` comes from. Please edit your source to include the actual relevant data.

Comment: What's the problem with your output? Is it only the missing `<li>` in the nested list? Your input doesn't match the data in the output.

Comment: I have updated ......   in the question.

Comment: If there are multiple <subsection> at the same level, it should be grouped and displayed under one <ul></ul> with multiple <li></li>

Comment: Thank you for all your answers.. Guess I need to do some learning in xslt before I start implementing the requirements. 'll try to use your answers to start with...

Comment: I have updated my questions showing what the requirements are and I would post the result If I am able to find a solution...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is adapted from [How can I wrap a group of adjacent elements using XSLT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3962161/how-can-i-wrap-a-group-of-adjacent-elements-using-xslt)

Consider the following input XML (I've added additional nodes and a third level subsection):

```
<body>
    <para>aaa</para>
    <subsection>
        <para>
            <paratext>LIST ITEM 1</paratext>
        </para>
    </subsection>
    <subsection>
        <para>
            <paratext>LIST ITEM 2</paratext>
        </para>
        <subsection>
            <para>
                <paratext>CHILD LISt ITEM2 ITEM 1 </paratext>
            </para>
        </subsection>
        <subsection>
            <para>
                <paratext>CHILD LISt ITEM2 ITEM 2 </paratext>
            </para>
            <subsection>
                <para>
                    <paratext>CHILD LISt ITEM2 ITEM 2 </paratext>
                </para>
            </subsection>
        </subsection>
    </subsection>
    <para>bbb</para>
</body>
```

when the following stylesheet is applied to the above XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:key name="kFollowing" match="subsection[preceding-sibling::*[1][self::subsection]]"
        use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::subsection
        [not(preceding-sibling::*[1][self::subsection])])"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="body">
        <text>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </text>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="subsection
        [not(preceding-sibling::*[1][self::subsection])]">
        <ul>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
            <xsl:apply-templates mode="copy" select="key('kFollowing', generate-id())"/>
        </ul>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="subsection[preceding-sibling::*[1][self::subsection]]"/>

    <xsl:template match="subsection" mode="copy">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="para[paratext]">
        <li>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </li>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="paratext">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

it produces:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<text>
   <para>aaa</para>
   <ul>
      <li>LIST ITEM 1</li>
      <li>LIST ITEM 2</li>
      <ul>
         <li>CHILD LISt ITEM2 ITEM 1 </li>
         <li>CHILD LISt ITEM2 ITEM 2 </li>
         <ul>
            <li>CHILD LISt ITEM2 ITEM 2 </li>
         </ul>
      </ul>
   </ul>
   <para>bbb</para>
</text>
```

Answer (score 0):

This has a lot of assumptions about the format but with this example xml:

```
<body>
    <subsection>
        <para>
            <paratext>LIST ITEM 1</paratext>
        </para>
    </subsection>
    <subsection>
        <para>
            <paratext>LIST ITEM 2</paratext>
        </para>
        <subsection>
            <para>
                <paratext>LIST ITEM 2</paratext>
            </para>
            <para>
                <paratext>LIST ITEM 2</paratext>
            </para>
        </subsection>
        <subsection>
            <para>
                <paratext>LIST ITEM 2</paratext>
            </para>
            <para>
                <paratext>LIST ITEM 2</paratext>
            </para>
        </subsection>
    </subsection>
</body>
```

and this example xslt:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="/body">
        <text>
            <ul>
                <xsl:apply-templates />
            </ul>
        </text>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/body/subsection/subsection">
        <ul>
             <xsl:apply-templates /> 
        </ul>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="paratext">
        <li>
             <xsl:apply-templates /> 
        </li>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

the result is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<text>
   <ul>
      <li>LIST ITEM 1</li>
      <li>LIST ITEM 2</li>
      <ul>
         <li>LIST ITEM 2</li>
         <li>LIST ITEM 2</li>
      </ul>
      <ul>
         <li>LIST ITEM 2</li>
         <li>LIST ITEM 2</li>
      </ul>
   </ul>
</text>
```

Comment: Thanks. This is what I was trying to achieve with the exception that I do not want to have an empty </ul> if there are no <subsection> in the input xml

Comment: Also the body tag is expected to have other tags which should not be blocked from "outputing"...

Answer (score 0):

I hope you get some idea for your final solution from this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="/body">
        <text>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="child::subsection[1]" />
        </text>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="subsection">
        <ul>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="child::para" />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::subsection/para" />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="../subsection/subsection[1]" />
        </ul>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="para">
        <li>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </li>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This doesn't yet work well with multiple nested layers. You will have to change the line
    <xsl:apply-templates select="../subsection/subsection[1]" />.

Answer (score 0):

This stylesheet adds another `<ul>` level for the second level. If you have no more than two or three levels its quite simple:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="body">
        <text>
            <ul>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="subsection/para"/>
                <ul><xsl:apply-templates select="subsection/subsection"/></ul>
            </ul>
        </text>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="paratext">
        <li><xsl:apply-templates /></li>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is the output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<text>
   <ul>
      <li>LIST ITEM 1</li>
      <li>LIST ITEM 2</li>
      <ul>
         <li>CHILD LISt ITEM2 ITEM 1 </li>
         <li>CHILD LISt ITEM2 ITEM 2 </li>
      </ul>
   </ul>
</text>
```