# XSLT Wrap arbitrary elements except one

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I was following [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3962161/how-can-i-wrap-a-group-of-adjacent-elements-using-xslt) but still can not resolve bellow described issue. Inside `<ol>` elements I need to wrap arbitrary elements (/nodes) into `<li>` according this example:

```
<ol>
    text
    <p>text</p>
    <li>
        text
        <p>text</p>
    </li>
    <p>text</p>
    text
    <sub>text</sub>
</ol>
```

Convert to:

```
<ol>
    <li>
        text
        <p>text</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        text
        <p>text</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <p>text</p>
        text
        <sub>text</sub>
    </li>
</ol>
```

I am using xslt 1.0.
Highly appreciate any help!

UPDATED EXAMPLE

```
<root>
    <ol>
        text
        <p>text</p>
        <li>
           text
           <p>text</p>
        </li>
        <p>text</p>
        text
        <sub>text</sub>
    </ol>
    <ol>
        text
        <p>text</p>
    </ol>
</root>
```

Convert to:

```
<root>
    <ol>
        <li>
            text
            <p>text</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            text
            <p>text</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>text</p>
            text
            <sub>text</sub>
        </li>
    </ol>
    <ol>
        <li>
            text
            <p>text</p>
        </li>
    </ol>
</root>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try to solve it as Muenchian grouping, where the key counts the `preceding-sibling::li` elements of all non `li` child nodes of `ol` elements:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:key name="group" match="ol/node()[not(self::li)]" use="count(preceding-sibling::li)"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ol/node()[not(self::li)][generate-id() = generate-id(key('group', count(preceding-sibling::li))[1])]">
        <li>
            <xsl:copy-of select="key('group', count(preceding-sibling::li))"/>
        </li>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ol/node()[not(self::li)][not(generate-id() = generate-id(key('group', count(preceding-sibling::li))[1]))]"/>

</xsl:transform>
```

Online sample at http://xsltransform.net/pPzifpy.

Comment: Thanks! I've just realized that in the mentioned example I determined `<ol>` as a root element. But it is not exactly my case. Therefore, I updated question. I will try to adapt your solution.