# Wrap nodes in new parent node/element

Tags: xml, xslt, nodes, word-wrap

I'm trying to wrap `<code-text>` in a `div` element.

**Sample code:**

```
<xsl:variable name="smallcase" select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'" />
<xsl:variable name="uppercase" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'" />

<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<code-text ATTRIBUTE="JSON">...</code-text>
<code-text ATTRIBUTE="SOAP">...</code-text>
<p>...</p>
<code-text ATTRIBUTE="JSON">...</code-text>
<code-text ATTRIBUTE="SOAP">...</code-text>
<code-text ATTRIBUTE="JSON">...</code-text>
<code-text ATTRIBUTE="SOAP">...</code-text>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<code-text ATTRIBUTE="JSON">...</code-text>
<code-text ATTRIBUTE="SOAP">...</code-text>
```

I've seen a couple of suggestions on this site already, but when I reproduce their solutions, it hasn't worked 100%.
The closest I got, was from [How can I wrap a group of adjacent elements using XSLT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3962161/how-can-i-wrap-a-group-of-adjacent-elements-using-xslt), but for some reason, it keeps adding the paragraph after as well.

**So this is basically where I'm at:**

```
<xsl:template match="code-text[@ATTRIBUTE]">
    <xsl:element name="div">
        <xsl:attribute name="class">
            <xsl:text>codes</xsl:text>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:call-template name="code-text" />
    </xsl:element>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::node()[not(self::code-text[@ATTRIBUTE])][1]" />
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="code-text[@ATTRIBUTE][preceding-sibling::node()[1]/self::code-text[@ATTRIBUTE]]" name="code-text">
    <xsl:text>Code goes here: </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="translate(@ATTRIBUTE, $uppercase, $smallcase)" /><xsl:element name="br" />
    <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::node()[1]/self::code-text[@ATTRIBUTE]" />
</xsl:template>
```

**But this outputs:**

```
<div class="codes">
Code goes here: JSON<br>
Code goes here: SOAP
</div>
<p>...</p>
Code goes here :SOAP
<p>...</p>
```

So the last SOAP and the Paragraph after it is repeated.

I want:

```
<div class="codes">
Code goes here: JSON<br>
Code goes here: SOAP
</div>
<p>...</p>
etc...etc...etc
```

**Update
To clarify about repeating json/soap/json/soap:**

```
<code-text ATTRIBUTE="JSON">...</code-text>
<code-text ATTRIBUTE="SOAP">...</code-text>
<code-text ATTRIBUTE="JSON">...</code-text>
<code-text ATTRIBUTE="SOAP">...</code-text>
```

I want to become:

```
<div class="codes">
Code goes here: JSON<br>
Code goes here: SOAP
</div>
<div class="codes">
Code goes here: JSON<br>
Code goes here: SOAP
</div>
```

Instead of:

```
<div class="codes">
Code goes here: JSON<br>
Code goes here: SOAP<br>
Code goes here: JSON<br>
Code goes here: SOAP
</div>
```

Comment: Is the first code sample the XML input you want to transform? If so, why does it contain `xsl:variable` elements? Also, can you use XSLT 2.0 and `for-each-group group-adjacent` or are you limited to XSLT 1.0?

Comment: The xsl:variable can be disregarded, it's there for xsl:value-of in the transformation.

I think XSLT 1 is the preferred version, I'm using PHP 5.6 as parser and I have no control over the library it uses.
But I'm pretty sure the server I'm on, only supports 1.0 at the moment of this comment.

Comment: Your "clarification" is more confusing than clarifying. Please explain the required logic **in words** before giving an example.

Comment: I was pointing to @MartinHonnen solution, which is close to what I'm aiming at.
Small update made, just for you ;)

Comment: I am afraid that doesn't help me at all. I could read this as: create a `div` for each group of  `code-text` elements, starting with  `<code-text ATTRIBUTE="JSON">`. Or create a `div` for each pair of `<code-text ATTRIBUTE="JSON"/><code-text ATTRIBUTE="SOAP"/>`. Or any other of many possible interpretations that your example fits.

Comment: For every pair is the accurate interpretation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a `div` for each **pair** of `<code-text ATTRIBUTE="JSON"/><code-text ATTRIBUTE="SOAP"/>` you could do simply:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <body>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="p | code-text[@ATTRIBUTE='JSON']"/>
    </body>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="code-text">
     <div class="codes">
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
        <br/>
        <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::code-text[1]" />
     </div>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to the following **well-formed** example input:

**XML**

```
<root>
    <p>a</p>
    <p>b</p>
    <code-text ATTRIBUTE="JSON">c1</code-text>
    <code-text ATTRIBUTE="SOAP">c2</code-text>
    <p>d</p>
    <code-text ATTRIBUTE="JSON">e1</code-text>
    <code-text ATTRIBUTE="SOAP">e2</code-text>
    <code-text ATTRIBUTE="JSON">f1</code-text>
    <code-text ATTRIBUTE="SOAP">f2</code-text>
    <p>g</p>
    <p>h</p>
    <code-text ATTRIBUTE="JSON">i1</code-text>
    <code-text ATTRIBUTE="SOAP">i2</code-text>
</root>
```

the result will be:

```
<body>
   <p>a</p>
   <p>b</p>
   <div class="codes">c1<br/>c2</div>
   <p>d</p>
   <div class="codes">e1<br/>e2</div>
   <div class="codes">f1<br/>f2</div>
   <p>g</p>
   <p>h</p>
   <div class="codes">i1<br/>i2</div>
</body>
```

Comment: So I could basically do `<xsl:apply-templates select="p | code-text[@ATTRIBUTE"/>`
If I wanted anything else in the `@ATTRIBUTE`, looks like what I need :) I'll try it out when I can access my code, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The XSLT 1.0 stylesheet

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:output method="html"/>

    <xsl:variable name="smallcase" select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'" />
    <xsl:variable name="uppercase" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'" />

    <xsl:key name="head"
        match="code-text[@ATTRIBUTE][preceding-sibling::*[1][self::code-text[@ATTRIBUTE]]]"
        use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::code-text[not(preceding-sibling::*[1][self::code-text[@ATTRIBUTE]])][1])"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="code-text[not(preceding-sibling::*[1][self::code-text[@ATTRIBUTE]])]">
        <div class="codes">
            <xsl:apply-templates select=". | key('head', generate-id())" mode="output"/>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="code-text[@ATTRIBUTE][preceding-sibling::*[1][self::code-text[@ATTRIBUTE]]]"/>

    <xsl:template match="code-text" mode="output">
        <xsl:text>Code goes here: </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="translate(@ATTRIBUTE, $uppercase, $smallcase)" /><br/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

transforms

```
<body>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <code-text ATTRIBUTE="JSON">...</code-text>
    <code-text ATTRIBUTE="SOAP">...</code-text>
    <p>...</p>
    <code-text ATTRIBUTE="JSON">...</code-text>
    <code-text ATTRIBUTE="SOAP">...</code-text>
    <code-text ATTRIBUTE="JSON">...</code-text>
    <code-text ATTRIBUTE="SOAP">...</code-text>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <code-text ATTRIBUTE="JSON">...</code-text>
    <code-text ATTRIBUTE="SOAP">...</code-text>
</body>
```

into

```
   <p>...</p>

   <p>...</p>

   <div class="codes">Code goes here: json<br>Code goes here: soap<br></div>


   <p>...</p>

   <div class="codes">Code goes here: json<br>Code goes here: soap<br>Code goes here: json<br>Code goes here: soap<br></div>




   <p>...</p>

   <p>...</p>

   <div class="codes">Code goes here: json<br>Code goes here: soap<br></div>


</body>
```

Comment: Almost what I want, thanks! but I would prefer if:
`<code-text ATTRIBUTE="JSON">...</code-text>`

`<code-text ATTRIBUTE="SOAP">...</code-text>`

`<code-text ATTRIBUTE="JSON">...</code-text>`

`<code-text ATTRIBUTE="SOAP">...</code-text>`
became:
`<div class="codes">code..json...code...soap</div>`

`<div class="codes">code..json...code...soap</div>`
:/